# How to make the text and bg-image("cover" doens't fully help) follow the size of the browser?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make the trial site as responsive as possible with the help of CSS and bootstrap,but encountered 2 problems.

When I try to make the image cover the whole page with command `background-size:cover` it does make the background responsive to certain extent,but when the window of the browser is too small,it creates duplicates of the bg-image:[image: duplicates].

As I understand this happens because of bg-image size,but can I somehow fix this situation?I tried to manipulate the background-size,but it didn't help,I used URL of another background,but it still had the same problem.

The second problem occurs with the text.I try to make it's position responsive to the page size,but it is still left cut like shown above,or not responsive like below.The `font-size:5vw` is used to only work with the size of the font.I tried to apply all the `position` methods,but they didn't help.Flexbox's wrap too doesn't help in the problem.So I would like to know if there is some way to make text responsive to the window size(wrap)?
[image: cutting]

Code:
html:
`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Who am I?</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="page_style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark bg-custom">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d9/Icon-round-Question_mark.svg/600px-Icon-round-Question_mark.svg.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="question mark">
                Who am I?
              </a>
            </nav>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">About me</a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Landing page <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">More information</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      My knowledge
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Programming tools/languages I can use</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Languages I know</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="">My projects(portfolio)</a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section>
            <h1>Wellcome!</h1>
        </section>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`

CSS:
`

```
body{
    background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/27/8a/df/278adfb7b82fdc9101bdefc94faa8eca.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}

header{
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 10px 4px 4px rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.navbar{
     background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(145, 110, 52, .4), rgba(145, 93, 52, .4), rgba(145, 76, 52, .4)) !important;
}

section {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 500px;
    left: 450px;
    right: 450px;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 5vw;
}
```

`
Thanks in advance and if there are some inconviniences in the text,let me know so I will not make the same mistakes in the future!
Have a good day!

Comment: background: #fff url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/27/8a/df/278adfb7b82fdc9101bdefc94faa8eca.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed /cover;

Comment: @Luís P. A. Thanks for help!It's working now!But can you send me the site where I can find the explanation of the programm or can you explain yourself if you have time?I can pretty much understand everything,but `#fff` and `/cover` parts confuse me.I saw similar command in the past,but it dind't have these parts and didn't work.

Comment: background: bg-color bg-image  bg-repeat position bg-attachment /bg-size; - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp

Comment: The color #fff, is if there is a problem with the image background, if the image not show it will replace by that color. Cover resize the background image to the entire container, even if it has to stretch the image or cut a little bit off one of the edges

Comment: @Luís P. A. Thank you for detailed answer!You helped me!But do you know what attribute to apply to make text do the same?